# Web SQL - Insert if not exists or Unique column?

Tags: html, cordova, web-sql

I try to execute `insert or ignore into  WDCategory(name,userID) values('Cate 1',1)` which name is a `unique` column but not successful if there is a record with same name in the table. "Not Successful" means that the query fail instead of execute and insert nothing. I have try `insert into  WDCategory(name,userID) values('Cate 1',1) If Not Exists` but nothing change.

Update: I try 
`insert or replace into  WDCategory(name,userID) values('Cate 1',1)`
it works. But the record now have a new id (auto increase). Is there any way to keep the old values?

Please help!